# How to test and write test cases for ReactJS app with Protractor?

Tags: reactjs, testing, protractor, frontend

I have been trying to test my own React app with Protractor but I don't know the correct syntax of test cases. I searched few things like:

```
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

The command is useful but still I don't know how to write test cases for React app. The tutorials are available for Angular only, like for example how to click on a certain button, how to write in input box, how to verify test result, how to match values, how to get title, etc.
Kindly guide me in this because I need Protractor for it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks useful https://medium.com/@abhinabaghosh.1994/test-your-react-app-efficiently-with-protractor-b8406db9148f

Comment: i saw this earlier, i'm confused on how to get result in the end and see if it's correct or not?

Comment: plus there are hooks as well consist of different states i'm confused like hell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about protractor is it isn't really language specific. You can test react pages just like any other page.  Make sure to set ignoreSynchronization before you visit a non angular page and all those tutorials should work.

```
// if true, ignore synchornization for testing non-angular pages.
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

You may have to replace the angular waits with your own.